# Turn off AutoComplete WooCommerce Checkout Page Form Fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set the autocomplete to `new-password` **only** on the *billing address 1* (street address) field so the modern browsers don't give the option to autofill on that field.

Is there a way to do it through a WooCommerce function?

**What I have tried so far?**

So looking at the output of the `woocommerce_checkout_fields`, I see the autocomplete is present (see screenshot below). I have tried to change it with the code below but it doesn't work. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    
    
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['autocomplete'] = 'new-password';
    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

[image]

Also, I found this on [Woocommerce - Turn Off Autocomplete in Checkout Fields via "autocomplete=new-password"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73295161/woocommerce-turn-off-autocomplete-in-checkout-fields-via-autocomplete-new-pas) where all fields have been set to `new-password`, but I don't think it's a nice solution (it changes all the fields).

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code you tried for mistake review and testing.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I have added the function I tried

Comment: The code is correct, so either you are using any checkout field editor plugin that is overriding the fields or you have conflicts with other plugins & themes. You can try to set priority to **99** maybe priority will solve the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vijay's comment I started to investigate what could be the cause of the issue. Found out my code works, it was the address autocompletion JS added by Google Places API that's setting the autocomplete attribute to `off`.

I will contact Google Developer Console support to see if there's a way to mitigate this.